# Get complete Touch Area/Space on the screen IOS

Tags: ios, ios7, ios8, uigesturerecognizer, uitouch

Is there any way to find the touched area/space in the screen (e.g, if you kept your thumb on the screen it needs to return the frame area covered by thumb)?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

New in iOS 8.0 is the [majorRadius](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITouch_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITouch/majorRadius) property of `UITouch` that should give you the data you need:

> Use the value in this property to determine the size of the touch that was reported by the hardware. This value is an approximation of the size and can vary by the amount specified in the majorRadiusTolerance property.